# How to pull an alias from native query in JPA

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm trying to pull an alias from native query in JPA, something like (SUM,COUNT), Well the method can return an integer if i pulled SUM or COUNT perfectly **(ONLY if i pulled it alone)** .
but how can i pull it with the rest of object? here is a sample what i am trying to do

```
@Entity
@Table("hotels")

public class Hotel {
    @Column(name="id")
    @Id
    private int hotelId;

    @Column(name="hotel_name")
    private String hotelName;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Availability>list;

    private int avaialbeCount; //this one should be Aliased and need to be pulled by none column
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface HotelRepository extends JpaRepository<Hotel,Integer>{
@Query(value="select h.*,a.count(1) as avaialbeCount from hotels h INNER JOIN availability a on (a.hotel_id=h.hotel_id) group by a.date",nativeQuery=true)
public List<Hotel> getHotels();

}
```

in the above repository. im trying to get avaialbeCount with hotel columns but im unable to pull it, however i can pull it by removing the select h.* and keep select COUNT only and make the method returns Integer instead of Hotel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JPQL, something like this

```
@Query("SELECT new test.Hotel(h.hotelName, count(h)) FROM Hotel h GROUP BY h.hotelName")
```

to use this `new test.Hotel(h.hotelName, count(h))`  construction, you need constructor like

```
public Hotel(String hotelName, Long avaialbeCount) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
    this.avaialbeCount = avaialbeCount;
}
```

**Example:**

*Repository:*

```
package test;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface HotelRepo extends JpaRepository<Hotel, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT new test.Hotel(h.hotelName, count(h)) FROM Hotel h GROUP BY h.hotelName")
    List<Hotel> getHotelsGroupByName();
}
```

*Entity:*

```
package test;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "hotels")
public class Hotel {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long hotelId;

@Column(name = "hotel_name")
private String hotelName;

@Transient
private Long avaialbeCount;

public Hotel() {
}

public Hotel(String hotelName) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
}

public Hotel(String hotelName, Long avaialbeCount) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
    this.avaialbeCount = avaialbeCount;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Hotel{" +
            "hotelId=" + hotelId +
            ", hotelName='" + hotelName + '\'' +
            ", avaialbeCount=" + avaialbeCount +
            '}';
    }
}
```

`@Transient` annotation is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database.

Comment: sounds logical, but why you used Transient ?

Comment: Can't i do it by nativw query ? should i use JPQL?

Comment: *Transient* is used for fields which didn't stored in database and we can calculate this fields, like count or average

Comment: JPQL is always works in this situation and i have never tried to solve this with native query...